# Itunes connect app rejection because of app name is similar to other apps already on the App Store

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

Our ios app rejected because of reason,

22.2 - Apps that contain false, fraudulent or misleading representations or use names or icons similar to other Apps will be rejected
22.2 Details

Your app or its metadata contains misleading content. Specifically, your app name is similar to other apps already on the App Store.

Next Steps

Please remove or revise any misleading content in your app and its metadata.

Since your iTunes Connect Application State is Rejected, a new binary will be required. Make the desired metadata changes when you upload the new binary.

NOTE: Please be sure to make any metadata changes to all App Localizations by selecting each specific localization and making appropriate changes.

But here my question. While creating app in itunes connect it has to through error like "app name already taken"(We faced this error) . But we didn't get that error . but app is rejected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably should do a search on iTunes before picking your app name to verify it is fairly distinct.  Is your app name 'Next Steps'?  Doing a google search you will find that an app named 'Next-Steps' already exists.  Because this is basically identical except for whitespace or non-alphabetic characters, Apple will reject the submission on review.

Answer (score 0):

While creating name on ItunesConnect it wont tell give you any warnings as such as it is still on your end. Only when u upload it, does Apple developers checks all the guidelines and verifies your application.

Its pretty standard to at least go through the apple guidelines before you submit your application.[Here](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) is the link for it.